# 2sxc: How to disable searching indexing

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

We are using a 2sxc module on an DNN Evoq install, there are multiple instances of 2sxc module app on a page which are inserted in lot of pages.

Can we disable search from indexing the content of one particular 2sxc module through its template file using razor code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can :)

It's a bit tricky but each razor can modify what / how something is indexed, this is often needed when indexing List/Details-pages. Here's the starting point in the docs: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/Razor-SexyContentWebPage.CustomizeSearch

I would try the following (haven't tried it myself, but should work)

```
@functions
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Populate the search - ensure that each entity has an own url/page
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="searchInfos"></param>
  /// <param name="moduleInfo"></param>
  /// <param name="startDate"></param>
  public override void CustomizeSearch(Dictionary<string, List<ToSic.SexyContent.Search.ISearchInfo>> searchInfos, DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime startDate)
  {
      // clear the search-infos
      searchInfos["Default"] = new List<ToSic.SexyContent.Search.ISearchInfo>();
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't get my head around it, could you help with a sample code? Because my efforts has resulted in general exception errors in the admin log